# openapi - regex for not allowing whitespace or hyphen

Tags: java, regex, openapi

Am using openapi 3.0.3 to autogenerate my Spring Boot based REST API...

Inside `src/main/resources/openapi/schema/PurchaseOrder.yaml`:

```
openapi: '3.0.3'
info:
  title: 'Purchase Order'  
  version: '1.0'
paths: {}

components:
  schemas:
    PurchaseOrder:
      title: 'Purchase Order'
      type: 'object'
      properties:
        account:
          type: 'string'
          description: Identifier for account making the purchase
          example: 1
          minLength: 1
          pattern: '^\s-$'
```

---

So, I need it to include alphanumeric values but no whitespaces (tried using this `pattern: '^\s-$'`) - can't have whitespaces at all...

When trying:

```
{
    account: 'a b'
}
```

This is what I received as a JSON Response:

```
"validationErrors": [
  {
    "field": "account",
    "message": "must match \"^\\s-$\""
  }
]
```

---

This same validation error also happens when I try a valid JSON (containing more than one char and no whitespaces and no hyphens):

```
{
   'account': 'ab'
}
```

This should have been valid and not thrown any validation errors...

---

How can I enforce no whitespaces and/or no hyphens at all using regex inside this yaml file?

Comment: Yes, its looking / allowing only one whitespace char and a dash but I want it to `disallow` ANY whitespace chards and ANY dashes.

Comment: `^[^\s-]+$` should work